# Firebase not getting initialized

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to get the token from firebase. But message I get is firebase initialization is unsuccessful.

App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.siddhi.contactsapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/michelelacorte/maven/" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Firebase :

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.siddhi.contactsapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" />
        <service
            android:name="com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.DetailViewActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.StartUpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service  android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MessageService"></service>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.InviteContactsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.PendingInvitesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pending_invites"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MessageService$SmsSentReceiver">
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MessageService$SmsDeliveredReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have added services to manifest. Also added the libraries which are required. Still I am unable to get the token. I have added project to the firebase console.

What am I missing? Can anyone help please? Thank you..

Comment: Have you started your service anywhere?

Comment: Have you put your json file (google-services.json) created by fire base in your project

Comment: What do you mean? I am running this on app to get the token. @VivekMishra

Comment: yes I have added the file in project. @MihirPatel

Comment: you have to start your `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` somewhere using `startService`

Comment: and one more thing when you created project on firebase have you mentioned package name correctly as same as in your project

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'       
Try adding this two latest firebase dependencies

Comment: MyFirebaseInstanceIDService fb = new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService();
        fb.startService(getIntent());  like this? @VivekMishra

Comment: I tried Adding latest services. Dosen't work.Also package name is correct at firebase console. @MihirPatel

Comment: Your are missing this dependency - compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

Comment: I think service gets start by itself, isn't it? @VivekMishra

Comment: The sample from google developer's console dose not contain 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'  this dependency. Still it works.. I am still trying by adding it,...@MihirPatel

Comment: dosen't work with that dependency too.@MihirPatel

Comment: for me it didn't and I don't think it will start itself any how.

Comment: can you please show me how to start? As I shown you is it a right way? @VivekMishra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start your service as it will not start automatically. To start your Firebase service use the following code:-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, FCMInstanceIDListenerService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Moreover,You are probably using older class path for google services. Update it with the latest version. For current version it will look like this.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: I tried this way still it shows same message. @Vivek Mishra

Comment: Have you configured your project correctly in console?

Comment: yes package name is correct in console. Created project. What more needs to be done? I followed google developers tutorial. @Vivek Mishra

Comment: Nothing else is remaining. Try sending push from console and debug your app and check whether debugger stops or not

Comment: for sending push I will need a token. I am not getting it. @Vivek Mishra

Comment: you can also send bulk notifications with firebase. That doesn't require token. You just have to select your app's package name from console. This will atleast confirm whether or not fcm has been integrated successfully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125178/discussion-between-sid-and-vivek-mishra).

Answer (score 2):

You are using a very old version of [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

In your project gradle file, replace:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'`

with

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

Answer (score -1):

Also Check that Internet Permission is given in your manifest file. that resolved my issue.